# Why are Hibernate/Jackson libraries required by my app?

Tags: android, hibernate, jackson

I created a simple Web Server which use Hibernate to store entities on a MySQL database. Also, as you can expect, it shares some libraries with the clients in the `<...>.shared>` package to access various resources. Among them, there are the POJO classes, annotated with both Hibernate and Jackson annotations. This is an example of a POJO class.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints =
{ @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "nick") })
public class User implements java.io.Serializable, RecognizedServerEntities
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Integer userId;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "threadAuthor",
      orphanRemoval = false)
  @Cascade({ CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
  private Set<Thread> userThreads = new HashSet<Thread>(0);
}
```

Now, I'm trying to create an android app that simply use these shared classes: the app doesn't need to know anything about Hibernate, Javax.persistence and maybe even Jackson annotations.
However, when I create a new Android project, it requires a lot of libraries.

```
74K  hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
5,1M hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar
38K  jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar
221K jackson-core-2.4.3.jar
1,1M jackson-databind-2.4.3.jar
180K javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar
714K org.restlet.jar
55K  shared.jar
```

Problem is that they greatly magnify the app size and slow down the development process, because I have to enable Multidex support.
So, how can I solve?
I can think of some solutions:

- Change the shared classes in some way to not expose the annotations. Is it a viable solution? How can I efficiently do this?
- Use ProGuard. I don't know if it's really a solution because I don't know anything about this tool, but for what I've read it could help to delete classes that aren't used at all in the project.

EDIT: I partially worked around the problem extracting only required casses from `hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar`, which is the greatest libraries. Still looking for most elegant solutions.

Comment: Sorry I am a little (lot) late, but I had a similar problem. I just made a mock library with just the annotations included in my code. This package would be extremely lightweight. So just define `@JsonInclude`, `@Entity`, `@Table`, so on so forth, in a mock library, then include that in your android app. It's not an elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of your application as having layers, you are currently using the same classes across the data access and view layers.

Your database isn't interested in the Jackson annotations, and your Android client isn't interested in the Hibernate annotations.

Two different approaches that I have seen for this are:
 - have a parallel 'view' layer representation of your objects that has the Jackson annotations which your application will populate by mapping from your Hibernate annotated data access layer
OR
 - have your client application not share the classes of the server application.  It parses the JSON and maps the structures into your own client specific model.

These approaches are equivalent, but just vary by where the mapping takes place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Btw, could you clarify your answer with some code?

Comment: It depends on which approach you prefer.  If your client doesn't really need the full object representation of your server side then you could just use JsonNode objects with readTree from Jackson's ObjectMapper.